# What is the error in my Largest Prime Number program?

Tags: java, primes

```
public class LargestPrimeFactor {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cases = scan.nextInt();
    int num = 0, temp = 0;
        while(cases!=0) {
        num = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i=2; i<=num; i++)
            if(num%i==0) {
                if(isPrime(i)) {
                    if(temp<i)
                        temp = i; //to always have the largest factor
                }
                num/=i; // to reduce the iterations for a large number.
            }
        System.out.println(temp);
        cases--;
    }
}

public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    if ( num > 2 && num%2 == 0 )
        return false;
    int top = (int)Math.sqrt(num) + 1;
    for(int i = 3; i < top; i+=2)
        if(num % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true; 
}
}
```

This code computes the largest prime factor of a number.
This gives an error 5/6 times from an Online Judge. I can't figure out the exception or error.
Please help...

Comment: Have you looked at the output it gives?

Comment: Have you looked at the input?

Comment: @Carcigenicate it doesn't show the inputs and output. just the time taken

Comment: @PeterLawrey  it doesn't show the inputs and output. just the time taken

Comment: @Shadow_Sphynx That's why you insert print statements or use a debugger. You need to learn to diagnose program by looking at what's going on some they're running.

Comment: I would try making `num` a `long` e.g. `long num = scan.nextLong();` The numbers could be large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset temp to 0 for each case.
Example input:

```
2 7 4
```

Expected output:

```
7
2
```

Actual output

```
7
7
```

Hope it helps.

Such errors are easier to make when you declare your variables earlier than you need them. Instead of

```
int num = 0, temp = 0;
    while(cases!=0) {
    num = scan.nextInt();
```

try

```
while (cases != 0) {
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    int temp = 0;
```

Comment: I think that was the issue. Thanks...
But there are two things I want to ask:

1.) I am still getting a **Runtime Error** on the last case. Any ideas why?
2.) If I declare a variable inside a loop wouldn't my program occupy more space?

Comment: 1) No, not really, sorry. You mean the last case the online judge runs? 2) Definitely not. The compiler is smart enough to use space in the same way in both cases, and even if it weren’t, it still would not take *more*. And not that you should worry if it did; space is *so* cheap.

Comment: Are there any requirements on what your program should do in case of illegal input? If so and if I were writing the online judge, I would definitely try some. Might this be the explanation for the runtime error? (Just tried -1 cases, your program runs in an infinite loop.)

Comment: yes the case the online judge runs. and i tried to change the datatypes from int to long if the judge was giving a large value, but then I got **Terminated Due to Timeout**. It is still not accepted.

Comment: Sounds like you’re on the right track. I haven’t figured out what goes, though.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler003

This is the link to the problem

Comment: Are you supposed to check the constraints or just trust the input fulfils them? In real life (if such a thing exists) you would definitely have to check.

Comment: You remembered to use `scan.nextLong()` too and also give `isPrime()` a long parameter? I can’t really see you could have an infinite loop in your program. It ran for a while when I gave it a very large long input, but for input under 10^12 (this is one of the constraints) it doesn’t seem to run for long in the cases I’ve tried.

Comment: Given input 999999999983 it does run for a couple of minutes on my computer before answering 229. I haven’t figured out what’s special about this number. There isn’t a timeout specified in the challenge. Do you know how long time the last case runs before giving “Terminated Due to Timeout”?

Comment: it says Terminated due to timeout 4s. now it is coming in 2/6 cases. same error

Comment: 4 seconds? That’s something of a requirement. Your program has room for improvement of performance, though.